# output buffering and a php page and ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page that i want to fetch the outputted html with ajax.  Here is my ajax code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".load_product_gallery").on("click",function () {
         $.ajax({
        url: 'product_gallery_popup.php', // The source
        cache: false, // Make sure results are not cached
        success: function (data) {
            $('.product_gallery_popup_container_2').html(data); 
        }
    });

    });


});

</script>
```

The `data` should be the outputted html of the php page.

My php page:

```
     ob_start(); // begin buffering content

  /* php page content */

  $html = ob_get_clean();  // grab buffered content and stop buffering
  return $html;
```

Will this return the php page outputted content in html to ajax?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried it?

Comment: `echo $html;` instead.

Comment: echo?  i have to return it to the ajax function.